# comparing two fields in report builder and returning a value of "yes" or "no"

Tags: reporting-services

Hello hope someone can help

i have two fields HB_Daily_Amt and Net_Daily i want to add a third textbox that if the HB_daily_amt is greater than the net_daily show "Full" else "Partial". however the HB_DAILY_AMT figure is always a negative value and the NET_DAILY is always a positive value.
if i use =ABS to convert the HB_DAILY_AMT i cant then figure out the formula to say =iif(Fields!HB_DAILY_AMT.Value > Fields!NET_DAILY.Value, "Full", "Partial") can someone advise what i am missing?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct to use ABS to convert your negative number to positive. The expression would look something like this...

```
=IIF(ABS(Fields!HB_DAILY_AMOUNT.Value) > Fields!NET_DAILY.Value, "Full", "Partial")
```

Comment: Hi Alan, the above solution worked perfectly however my underlying data, the HB_DAILY_AMT is 23.98857 and my NET_DAILY is 23.988571 as a result the end result says that these figures are PARTIAL rather than FULL and they should be FULL. i have tried everything i can think of to adjust the decimal value of the NET_DAILY and the HB_DAILY_AMT to be to two decimal places ie 23.99 so that the FULL/PARTIAL expression recognises them as the same values?

Comment: Just use `ROUND()`, so something like `=IIF(ABS(ROUND(Fields!HB_DAILY_AMOUNT.Value,2)) > ROUND(Fields!NET_DAILY.Value,2), "Full", "Partial")` .